# How to Resolve Unexpected "Flip-Flopping" of Input Action Values in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am encountering an unexpected issue in Unity where a state variable, specifically isMovementPressed, is "flip-flopping" or oscillating between two values even when I expect it to remain constant. Here's the context:

I've set up a state machine for my character where it transitions between different states based on input and other conditions.
I use the Unity Input Action System to detect when a movement action is being performed.
Upon pressing the movement input, I expect the character's state to consistently remain in the "Moving" state. However, when I hold down the movement key, the character's state seems to switch rapidly between "Idle" and "Moving".

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public enum PlayerState
{
    Idle,
    Moving,
    Dashing
}

[RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]
public class PlayerController : StateManager<PlayerState>
{
    public InputManager inputManager;
    internal CharacterController characterController;
    
    [SerializeField] internal float dashDuration = 0.5f;
    [SerializeField] private float tiltAngle = 30f; // hard limit for tilt angle
    [SerializeField] private float tiltSpeed = 15f; // how much tilt changes with velocity
    
    internal Vector3 velocity;
    internal Vector3 lastPosition;
    [SerializeField] internal Vector2 movementInputVector;
    internal bool isMovementPressed;
    internal bool isDashing;
    
    private void Awake()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        
        // Instantiate the states and populate the States dictionary.
        States[PlayerState.Idle] = new Idle(this);
        States[PlayerState.Moving] = new Moving(this);
        States[PlayerState.Dashing] = new Dashing(this);

        CurrentState = States[PlayerState.Idle]; 
    }
    
    internal void OnMovementInput(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {

        Vector2 inputValue = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        
        movementInputVector = inputValue;
        isMovementPressed = movementInputVector != Vector2.zero;
        
        Debug.Log(isMovementPressed);
    }
    
    internal void OnDashInput(InputAction.CallbackContext context) {

        if (context.GetButton() && !isDashing && isMovementPressed) {
            isDashing = true;
        }
    }
    
    private void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(isMovementPressed);
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Velocity();
        TiltPlayer();
    }
    
    private void Velocity() {
        
        Vector3 position = gameObject.transform.position;
        velocity = (position - lastPosition) / Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        lastPosition = position;
    }
    
    private void TiltPlayer()
    {
        float tilt = Mathf.Clamp(velocity.x, -tiltAngle , tiltAngle ); // calculate the tilt angle
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -tilt), Time.fixedDeltaTime * tiltSpeed); // calculate and assign the quaternion, tilting over the X axis
    }
    
    internal void Move(Vector2 inputVector)
    {
        Vector3 moveDirection = new Vector3(inputVector.x, 0f, inputVector.y);
        
        characterController.Move(moveDirection);
    }
    

}
```

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public enum InputEnvironment
{
    Menu,
    Player
}

public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputEnvironment InputEnvironment
    {
        get { return inputEnvironment; }
        set
        {
            SwitchActionMap(value, inputEnvironment);
            inputEnvironment = value;
        }
    }

    private InputEnvironment inputEnvironment;
    private UserActions inputActions;
    [SerializeField] private PlayerController player;
    
    private void Awake()
    {
        InitializeInputActions();
    }

    private void InitializeInputActions()
    {
        inputActions = new UserActions();
        InputEnvironment = InputEnvironment.Player;
    }

    #region ActionMapStates

    private void SwitchActionMap(InputEnvironment currentEnvironment, InputEnvironment previousEnvironment)
    {
        switch (previousEnvironment)
        {
            case InputEnvironment.Menu:
                OnMenuDisable();
                break;
            case InputEnvironment.Player:
                OnPlayerDisable();
                break;
        }

        switch (currentEnvironment)
        {
            case InputEnvironment.Menu:
                OnMenuEnable();
                break;
            case InputEnvironment.Player:
                OnPlayerEnable();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void OnMenuEnable()
    {
        inputActions.Menu.Enable();
    }

    private void OnMenuDisable()
    {
        inputActions.Menu.Disable();
    }

    private void OnPlayerEnable()
    {
        inputActions.Player.Enable();
        EnableMovementInput();
    }

    private void OnPlayerDisable()
    {
        inputActions.Player.Disable();
        DisableMovementInput();
    }

    #endregion

    #region PlayerActionStates

    public void EnableMovementInput()
    {
        inputActions.Player.Movement.started += player.OnMovementInput;
        inputActions.Player.Movement.canceled += player.OnMovementInput;
        inputActions.Player.Movement.performed += player.OnMovementInput;
        
        inputActions.Player.Dodge.started += player.OnDashInput;
    }

    public void DisableMovementInput()
    {
        inputActions.Player.Movement.started -= player.OnMovementInput;
        inputActions.Player.Movement.canceled -= player.OnMovementInput;
        inputActions.Player.Movement.performed -= player.OnMovementInput;
        
        inputActions.Player.Dodge.started -= player.OnDashInput;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using UnityEngine;

/// <summary>
/// References all states, handles transitions between states, and updates the current state.
/// </summary>
public abstract class StateManager<EState> : MonoBehaviour where EState : Enum
{
    protected Dictionary<EState, BaseState<EState>> States = new();
    
    protected BaseState<EState> CurrentState;

    protected bool IsTransitioningState = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (CurrentState == null) { return; }
        CurrentState.Enter();
    }
    
    private void Update()
    {
        if (CurrentState == null) { return; }
        EState nextState = CurrentState.GetNextState();
        //Debug.Log(nextState);
        if (!IsTransitioningState && nextState.Equals(CurrentState.StateKey))
            CurrentState.Update();
        else if (!IsTransitioningState) TransitionToState(nextState);
    }
    
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (CurrentState == null) { return; }
        CurrentState.FixedUpdate();
    }
    
    public void TransitionToState(EState stateKey)
    {
        IsTransitioningState = true;
        CurrentState.Exit();
        CurrentState = States[stateKey];
        CurrentState.Enter();
        IsTransitioningState = false;
    }
    
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (CurrentState == null) { return; }
        CurrentState.OnTriggerEnter(col);
    }
    
    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
    {
        if (CurrentState == null) { return; }
        CurrentState.OnTriggerStay(col);
    }
    
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
    {
        if (CurrentState == null) { return; }
        CurrentState.OnTriggerExit(col);
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(10f, 10f, 200f, 100f));
        string content = CurrentState != null ? CurrentState.Name : "(no current state)";
        GUILayout.Label($"<color='black'><size=40>{content}</size></color>");
        GUILayout.EndArea();
    }
}
```

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

/// <summary>
/// Base class for all states.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="EState"></typeparam>
public abstract class BaseState<EState> where EState : Enum
{
    public BaseState(EState key)
    {
        StateKey = key;
    }
    
    public EState StateKey { get; private set; }
    public string Name => StateKey.ToString();
    
    // Abstract methods are required to override
    public abstract void Enter();
    public abstract EState GetNextState();
    
    // Virtual methods are optional to override
    public virtual void Exit() { }
    public virtual void Update() { }
    public virtual void FixedUpdate() { }
    public virtual void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) { }
    public virtual void OnTriggerStay(Collider col) { }
    public virtual void OnTriggerExit(Collider col) { }
    
    
}
```

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Idle : BaseState<PlayerState>
{
    private PlayerController playerController;

    public Idle(PlayerController playerController) : base(PlayerState.Idle)
    {
        this.playerController = playerController;
    }

    public override void Enter()
    {
        
    }

    public override void Exit()
    {
        
    }
    
    public override PlayerState GetNextState()
    {
        // If movement input is detected, transition to Moving
        if (playerController.isMovementPressed) 
        {
            return PlayerState.Moving;
        }
        
        return StateKey;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

```
public class Moving : BaseState<PlayerState>
{
    private PlayerController playerController;

    public Moving(PlayerController playerController) : base(PlayerState.Moving)
    {
        this.playerController = playerController;
    }

    public override void Enter()
    {
        
    }

    public override void Exit()
    {
        
    }
    
    public override void Update()
    {
        playerController.Move(playerController.movementInputVector);
    }
    
    public override PlayerState GetNextState()
    {
        // If the dash input is received while moving
        if (playerController.isDashing)
        {
            return PlayerState.Dashing;
        }

        // If no movement input is detected, return to Idle
        if (!playerController.isMovementPressed) 
        {
            return PlayerState.Idle;
        }
        return StateKey;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

```
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

// Used to extend the functionality of the unity input system and use it akin to the 
// legacy system
public static class InputActionButtonExtensions 
{
    // Extends the InputAction class to allow for the use of the legacy input system
    public static bool GetButton(this InputAction action) => action.ReadValue<float>() > 0;
    public static bool GetButtonDown(this InputAction action) => action.triggered && action.ReadValue<float>() > 0;
    public static bool GetButtonUp(this InputAction action) => action.triggered && action.ReadValue<float>() == 0;
    
    // Extends the InputAction.CallbackContext class to allow for the use of the legacy input system
    public static bool GetButton(this InputAction.CallbackContext context) => context.ReadValue<float>() > 0;
    public static bool GetButtonDown(this InputAction.CallbackContext context) => context.performed && context.ReadValue<float>() > 0;
    public static bool GetButtonUp(this InputAction.CallbackContext context) => context.performed && context.ReadValue<float>() == 0;
}
```

Has anyone else experienced this kind of issue with the Unity Input System or state machines in general? Are there any known nuances or bugs that might cause this kind of behaviour? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Through debugging, I've observed that the value of isMovementPressed and movementInputVector fluctuates. These values should remain constant and do if I debug.log within OnMovementInput() however they don't if I debug.log within update.

Comment: Wow thats a lot of code. And not really a [mcve] however it is hard to tell but i would say it is your logic of ismovmentpressed etc possibly incorrect. Simply on cwncel of ismovment you would set to idle assuming nothing else is also true such as fashing, jumping etc.

Comment: You registered same method to multiple events. Are you sure they provide same context? Try separating them and see which one is setting undesired value.

Comment: In my opinion, you're _really_ overcomplicating this. I don't know your project, but is such a state machine implementation really necessary at this point? What's wrong with a simple if-branch that uses `Input.GetKeyDown` or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, for anybody getting the same issue, this is a bug caused by copy and pasting a scene file. Setting up a new scene fixed this issue and now my fsm works!